# ndk8e debug error "Unable to detect application ABI's"

Tags: windows, debugging, android-ndk

OS: Windows8 x64

Eclipse: ADT bundle form http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

NDK: NDK8e for Windows 64 from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html.

I set Windows/Preference/Android/NDK to the corect NDK path.

What I do:

- Import the hello-jni sampe from %Android-NDK%/samples to Eclipse
- Modify in AndroidManifext.xml

  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" /> to <uses-sdkandroid:minSdkVersion="17" />`
- Add Native Support

  Right click the project, Android Tools/Add Native Support.
- Turn debug on

  Right click the project, Properties/"C/C++ build"/Build Settings, modify the Build command to "ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1"
- Set a breakpoint in the C code.
- Debug As/Android Native Application.

I hava do this in tow computer. But there are two error message.

One is like bellow:

```
[2013-06-12 00:03:09 - HelloJni] Unknown Application ABI:

[2013-06-12 00:03:09 - HelloJni] [2013-06-12 00:03:09 - HelloJni] Unable to detect application ABI's
```

The Other is like bellow:

```
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 73 libraries, e.g. /system/binnker.

Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.

Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?

warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.

GDB will retry eventurally.  Meanwhile, it is likely

that GDB is unable to debug shared library initializers

or resolve pending breakpoints after dlopen().
```

Comment: `Could not load shared library symbols for 73 libraries` is normal, you really don't have symbol info for system libraries on your device.

Answer (score 1):

One of the causes of such messages may be irregular CRLF in .xml or .properties files in the project root directory.

Comment: Did you edit the `project.properties` file or `AndroidManifest.xml` file after you imported the sample into eclipse?

Comment: I do the next things. modify the AndroidManifext.xml

Comment: I hava post more detail in the new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139200/ndk-debug-error-for-windowsx86

Comment: I fail to understand why you opened a new issue instead of updating the old one.

Comment: I've solved this problem after I reinstall my System. I don't know the detail about the reason until now.