# Cannot Natively Debug Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, adt

There have been a lot of forum posts on this but none of the suggestions have worked for me.

I have :

- android:debuggable="true" in my manifest file

  I'm building with ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1

  I have an API level 16 device and have set android:minSdkVersion="16"
  and android:targetSdkVersion="16" in my manifest

  I have set target=android-16 in my project.properties

When I try to natively debug I get lots of

"Unknown Application ABI" messages

and finally

"Unable to detect application ABI's"

My application runs fine and I can non-natively debug the java part okay.

Comment: The underlying process of initiating native debugging is fairly complicated so there are a lot of places where it can go wrong.  Given your difficulty, instrumenting likely problem locations with native logging may be a faster route to a solution.  There are quite few problems which cannot be found by *insightful* use of logging.

Comment: I hope "native logging" doesn't mean what I think it means :(

Comment: It means you have to think about what could be wrong with your code, and put in checks and debug messages to check your suspicions and verify that the parts you think are working fine actually are.  I'd be hesitant to trust a developer unable to solve problems in this way with any project of importance, no matter what interactive tools are *supposedly* available for *convenience*.

Comment: One of the causes could be mixed line endings, like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17048932/ndk8e-debug-error-unable-to-detect-application-abis

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you forgot to put `APP_ABI := all` (or specific abi) in your makefile.

Comment: Still getting the same problem with that added